# How to show module in multiple stores in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, store-view

Can anyone help me that how to show module in mutiple store view in magento1.9?
Actually my module show only in main website store when we select store then its not showing...so plz provide me the solution for that.

Comment: I think modules have global view only options are changed/hidden per store view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962066/magento-disable-module-for-any-particular-store

Comment: can i mark this question as duplicate or you can share your code or anything that help others to solve the same if they stuck. Just to keep the stackexchange clean

Comment: Yaa you can mark as a duplicate.

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: yes i have solved my problem.

Comment: than you can share yours as answer or the link